# Delphi - Can I use InternetReadFile for local file?

Tags: delphi, file, download, local, wininet

I need to use WinInet for download files.

I want to test it, but as I checked it first, it isn't working for local files.
(file://*)

This is needed for test the program without internet, or debug when the internet gone...

Firstly I need to check the file size for progress with HTTPRequest, and next I need to download the file...

As I saw none of these functions are working with local files...

But maybe I missed some option, or I used wrong url... like...

```
file://localhost/C:/temp/AV.GIF
```

Does anybody know about that:
a. Can I use these functions for local files?
b. And if the answer is yes, then how I need to change my code?

This example show how I use the WinInet:

```
function TDDWIToolObject.GetFileSize(out Size: Int64): boolean;
var
    hInet: HINTERNET;
    hConnect: HINTERNET;
    hRequest : HINTERNET;
    lpdwBufferLength: DWORD;
    lpdwReserved    : DWORD;
    ServerName: string;
    Resource: string;
    FileSizeBuffer : array[0..32] of char;
    SizeCard : Cardinal;
begin
    ParseURL(Url, ServerName, Resource);
    Result := False;
    Size := 0;

    hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(_UserAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
    if hInet=nil then begin
        FErrorCode := GetLastError;
        Exit;
    end;

    try

        hConnect := InternetConnect(hInet, PChar(ServerName), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
        if hConnect=nil then begin
            FErrorCode := GetLastError;
            Exit;
        end;

        try

            hRequest := HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, PChar('HEAD'), PChar(Resource), nil, nil, nil, 0, 0);
            if hRequest = nil then begin
                FErrorCode := GetLastError;
                Exit;
            end;

            try
                FillChar(FileSizeBuffer, SizeOf(FileSizeBuffer), #0);
                lpdwBufferLength := SizeOf(FileSizeBuffer);
                lpdwReserved :=0;
                if not HttpSendRequest(hRequest, nil, 0, nil, 0) then begin
                    FErrorCode := GetLastError;
                    Exit;
                end;

                if not HttpQueryInfo(
                    hRequest,
                    HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH,
                    @FileSizeBuffer, lpdwBufferLength, lpdwReserved) then begin

                    FErrorCode:=GetLastError;
                    Exit;
                end;

                Size := StrToInt64(StrPas(FileSizeBuffer));
                Result := True;

            finally
                InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
            end;

        finally
            InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
        end;

    finally
        InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
    end;

end;


function TDDWIToolObject.DownloadFile;
var
    hInet: HINTERNET;
    hFile: HINTERNET;
    pbuffer: Pointer;
    bytesRead: DWORD;
    Stm : TFileStream;
    TotalBytes : Int64;
    AbortIt : boolean;
begin
    Result := False;
    FErrorCode := -1;
    FAborted := False;
    hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(_UserAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
    if hInet = nil
        then begin
            FErrorCode := GetLastError;
            Exit;
        end;
    try
        hFile := InternetOpenURL(hInet, PChar(URL), PChar(FHeaders), Length(FHeaders), 0, 0);
        if hFile = nil
            then begin
                FErrorCode := GetLastError;
                Exit;
            end;
        try
            Stm := TFileStream.Create(FN, fmCreate);
            try
                GetMem(pbuffer, FBufferSize);
                try
                    TotalBytes := 0; AbortIt := False;
                    while (not FAborted) do begin
                        if not InternetReadFile(hFile, pbuffer, FBufferSize, bytesRead) then begin
                            FErrorCode := GetLastError;
                            Exit;
                        end;
                        if bytesRead > 0 then begin
                            Stm.WriteBuffer(pbuffer^, bytesRead);
                            if Assigned(FOnBytesArrived)
                                then begin
                                    inc(TotalBytes, bytesRead);
                                    FOnBytesArrived(Self, TotalBytes, AbortIt);
                                    if AbortIt
                                        then Abort;
                                end;
                        end else begin
                            break;
                        end;
                    end;
                finally
                    FreeMem(pbuffer);
                end;
                if not FAborted
                    then Result := True;
            finally
                Stm.Free;
            end;
        finally
            InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
        end;
    finally
        InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
    end;
end;
```

Thanks for every info, link, document, critic...

Comment: If you need to debug it - then just install some simplistic http server. Afterall if you'd make error in HTTP-related code you would not be able to debug it with non-HTTP protocol like `fopen`. There are a lot of tiny HTTP servers - just use them. For example: http://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not using just some internet-related function. You use namely `HttpOpenRequest` - HTTP. By its name, this would only work with HTTP or perhaps HTTP/SSL protocol. It should not even work for other internet protocols to get the file like FTP, BitTorrent, Gnutella and such.

file:// is URL protocol name, and it exactly means "do not go internet, open local file instead" so internet-related functions would probably not work on it.

And surely there is no way to issue GET or HEAD or other HTTP-only commands over it.

More so, there it would no way help you to debug HTTP-related bugs, for those bugs to reproduce would requre exactly HTTP traffic sequence repeated, perhaps even with given remote server version and configuration sometimes.

Install some local http server like TinyWeb, nginx or lighttpd - and do your debug.

There also were HTTP server demos in Synapse and mORMot libraries, so you can even make your own server for debugging.